# Copiar una fila entera de excel/google sheets y pegarla en un formulario

Tags: php, html

Tengo por un lado en excel/google sheets 4 columnas con: nombre, numero de telefono, ciudad y comentarios.

y por otro lado tengo un formulario común de contacto, en php/html

hasta el momento, copio cada dato por separado que hay en las celdas y los voy agregando manualmente en cada campo en mi html, lo que necesitaria es poder copiar toda la fila entera y una vez apretado ctrl+v en el html, que se peguen automaticamente, ya que los campos están en orden.

lo eh visto en ciertos formularios, pero no tengo idea por donde arrancar.

algun consejo/ayuda como lo puedo buscar/ que función deberia utilizar?

muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta sacada de la pregunta en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006468/copy-paste-from-excel-to-a-web-page

El problema es que cuando copias de excel, los delimitadores no se pierden, son tabulaciones entre las columnas y saltos de linea para las filas.

Si lo que quieres es poder copiar y pegar directamente, tendras que tener el excel igual que el formato de tus inputs del formulario.

El script a continuación realiza una tabla HTML a partir de los datos Excel copiados.

```
var data = $('input[name=excel_data]').val();
var rows = data.split("\n");

var table = $('<table />');

for(var y in rows) {
    var cells = rows[y].split("\t");
    var row = $('<tr />');
    for(var x in cells) {
        row.append('<td>'+cells[x]+'</td>');
    }
    table.append(row);
}

// Insert into DOM
$('#excel_table').html(table);
```

Si quieres algo más concreto, deberás cambiar tu pregunta, dandonos más datos como la estructura de tu formulario a rellenar.